# Can $\infty$ be used to index a set? For example $C_{\infty}$ or something like $\bigcap_{i=0}^{\infty}C_i=C_0\cap C_1\cap\cdots\cap C_{\infty}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation, infinity

Does
$$\bigcap_{i=0}^{\infty}C_i=C_0\cap C_1\cap\cdots\cap C_{\infty}?$$

I'm pretty sure that it is correct, but what does $C_{\infty}$ actually mean, I haven't studied infinity yet so I don't know if it's valid or what it means.

Comment: No, that's not valid. You could index up to an infinite ordinal using the standard ordering and that could make sense in certain contexts (eg transfinite induction intersection arguments in defining Borel sets), but your notation makes no sense in general, since $\infty$ does not denote a specific ordinal in general.

Comment: First time I see the notation $\bigcap_{i=0}^\infty C_i$ in my life. What does that mean?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio it means the intersection of an infinite family of sets $\{C_i\}_{i \in I} $ for some indexing set $I$. Comments are not the place to ask such questions: make your own post to ask such things.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Comments are precisely the place to ask for clarification on the post. Feel free to flag if you disagree.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen How is your $I$ related to $0,...,\infty$ ?

Comment: Your accepted answer contains incorrect information. For example, when it says that this is not meaningful notation. That's nonsense. The main problem with your equation is that each side is representing different intersections. When the notation $\bigcap_{i=0}^{\infty}C_i$ is used it really means intersection for all $0\leq i<\infty$. Compare with $\bigcap_{i=0}^{3}C_i$, which does mean $C_0\cap C_1\cap C_2\cap C_3$, with the index $3$ included. On the other hand, your right side is intersecting $C_i$ for all finite indexes and an extra one corresponding to the index $\infty$.

Comment: @NDB Disagree.  First off, the equality is wrong (since $\bigcap_{j=0}^{\infty}$ means $\bigcap_{j\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}}$).  Second, even if the right-hand side is *supposed* to mean "take the intersection of $C_j$ over all natural numbers $j$, then intersect that with an extra set $C_\infty$", the notation is ambiguous, at best.  It would be better to write $C_{\infty} \cap (C_1 \cap C_2 \cap C_3 \cap \dotsb)$ or $C_\infty \cap \bigcap_{j=0}^{\infty} C_j$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson You are disagreeing by saying what I said? OK. I "disagree" too, for that meaning of "disagree".

Comment: @NDB You made the claim that $C_1 \cap \dotsb \cap C_\infty$ represents the intersection of infinitely many sets labeled $C_j$ (for $j\in\mathbb{N}$), plus one more set, labeled $C_\infty$.  I disagree with that statement.  If that is the intended meaning, the notation $C_1 \cap \dotsb \cap C_\infty$ is ambiguous, at best, and pretty damn confusing in any setting.  I find it difficult that *anyone* would intended that meaning, particularly without some kind of parentheses to disambiguate the meaning.  But you are the one who said that my answer contains "incorrect information".

Comment: @XanderHenderson Your opinion. Not mathematics. All notations with $\ldots$ are ambiguous, still used and understood within their context.

Comment: @NDB Do you believe that your contrariness is being helpful to the person who asked this question? They asked if $\bigcap_{j=0}^{\infty} C_j$ means the same thing as $C_0 \cap C_1 \cap \dotsb C_{\infty}$.  Are you claiming that it does?  If not, do you believe that bringing in a non-standard and unusual usage to explain the right-hand side is helpful? As I said in my answer, there are somewhat esoteric situations in which one might want to write $C_1 \cap \dotsb \cap C_{\infty}$, but these are not useful or helpful for someone trying to understand what is meant by $\bigcap_{j=0}^{\infty} C_j$.

Comment: Particularly when you declare that my answer is *wrong*, without providing *any* evidence.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Your first question is answered, explicitly, in my first comment. And I didn't say wrong. Here is exact quote "contains incorrect information". Which one? That $C_0\cap\ldots\cap C_{\infty}$  doesn't make sense.

Comment: @NDB I never wrote "That $C_0\cap\ldots\cap C_{\infty}$  doesn't make sense."  Not in the absolute sense that you seem to have inferred.

Comment: @XanderHenderson "2. **Does the notation $C_0\cap C_1 \cap C_2 \cap \dotsb \cap C_{\infty}$ make sense?**

    No."

Comment: @NDB You have to read to the end of the line.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I did. All that follows is about how $\bigcap_{i=0}^{\infty}C_i$ and $C_0\cap C_1\cap \ldots\cap C_{\infty}$ differ, and nothing about the "No". Yet, everyone understood the same meaning for the latter, which evidences that the right side makes perfect sense. It is just not equal to the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two questions here:

1. **Can $\infty$ be used as an index?**

   Sure.  Any symbol at all can be used as an index.  It is just notation.  For example, it is very common to use $\infty$ as the index of a limiting object.  In the question, it would not be unreasonable to write
   $$ C_{\infty} = \bigcap_{j=0}^{\infty} C_j = C_0 \cap C_1 \cap C_2 \cap C_3 \cap \dotsb. $$
2. **Does the notation $C_0\cap C_1 \cap C_2 \cap \dotsb \cap C_{\infty}$ make sense?**

   No.  This is not really meaningful notation (except, possibly, in some very esoteric contexts which, if you are asking this question, are not relevant).  By convention, the notation
   $$\bigcap_{j=0}^{\infty} C_j$$
   means "take the intersection of all of the sets $C_j$, where $j$ is any natural number (or zero).  Another way of writing this is
   $$ \bigcap_{j\in\mathbb{N}} C_j. $$
   There is no set labeled $C_\infty$ in this collection of sets which are being intersected.

Answer (score 3):

Infinity *can* be used to index a set, but it's not very common.

The notation you are asking about means
$$
\bigcap_{i=0}^{\infty} C_i
=C_0\cap C_1\cap \cdots
$$
i.e. the set of points that are found in every $C_i.$